# Angular ng-options with filter getting infinite digest error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <select class="form-control"
            id="Title"
            name="Title"
            ng-model="positionList"
            ng-options="position as position.position_title for position in positions.data track by position.position_ID | filter:{is_active:1}">
    </select>
```

is_active is another key available as part of positions. This code works fine until I add a filter... then I get an infinite digests error

Comment: This is not good practice to update option. You should filter the list in controller.

Comment: Can you show us the positions variable?

Comment: @bclinga Please push your code to plunker. will update that for you.

Comment: Thanks- I agree it didn't feel optimal, I'm trying it the other way now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your ng-options to filter before the track by:

```
position as position.position_title for position in (positions.data | filter:{is_active:1}) track by position.position_ID
```